# Can i read hadoop file line by line

Tags: linux, shell, unix, hadoop

I wanna read line by line records in unix box from hadoop file system :

Example -

```
while read line

do 

echo "input record " $line
###some other logic i have here....
done < /user/want/to/read/from/hadoop/part00
```

Above code snippet shows me error -

```
**: cannot open [No such file or directory]**
```

How can i read from Hadoop using Unix tools?

Comment: In addition to the answer below, don't edit your script in a program that puts Windows line endings in it... (the most frequent cause of the `: cannot open ...` message you have there.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `hadoop fs` command to access contents of these files:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  echo "Read: $line"
done < <(hadoop fs -cat hdfs://nodename/filename)
```

Note that the `<()` construct requires bash; thus, your script needs to start with `#!/bin/bash`, not `#!/bin/sh`.